# mod rewrite issue with htaccess using Slim Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

im working on a app for a client in which they have a site with a few wordpress blogs on it
http://www.chasethepaper.com

in the root, the htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(yumninja_app_1_0|yumninja_app_1_0/.*)$
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

inside the root, i have a folder called

```
'yumninja_app_1_0'
```

inside the 'ap' folder i have an htaccess with

if you go to 
http://chasethepaper.com/yumninja_app_1_0/api/

it shows the index page, which is correct
however, if you go to

http://chasethepaper.com/yumninja_app_1_0/api/getReviews
it returns the wordpress 404

Here is the htaccess file inside the api folder

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess filwe.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(yumninja_app_1_0|yumninja_app_1_0/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

<IfModule Mod_php.c> 
 php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
 php_value post_max_size 20M
 php_value memory_limit 32M
</IfModule>
```

im really not sure why this is not working. it was a few days ago. i know /getReviews is valid since i copied the same folder structure to another sever and it worked correctly
http://javadash.com/yumninja_app_1_0/api/getReviews

Answer (score 0):

Check out the error.log file if the server is apache, it should provide useful information as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. It was because i had

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/({app_name}|{app_name}.*)$
```

inside the .htaccess file in the api folder. Once i removed it, it worked